# debug background service in android using intelliJ

Tags: android, service, background, intellij-idea

I recently switched from eclipse to IntelliJ for android development (due to the better team support w/ projects/modules).  However, when I try to debug the a background service, it appears this is not possible to do.  Has anyone successfully gotten intelliJ to debug a bg service?

many thanks
Ben

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. In the Android Run/Debug configuration disable `Deploy application` and enable `Do not launch Activity`.
2. In the toolbar use the `Attach debugger to Android process` button:
   [image: attach debugger]

Comment: sorry, the background service is not listed and I can't hit any breakpoints in the bg service when I do this.  In eclipse they'd have the list of running processing which I could then use to select the bg service and attach to the debugger.  It seems that I can only select the foreground/main application process.

Comment: Have you specified your process in AndroidManifest.xml through "android:process" attribute? IDE shows only processes related to your project

Comment: Also, you should use IDEA 11.1.2. 11.0.x versions of IDEA contain related bug

Comment: i discovered the problem.  It was because my service process was named with :MyBackgroundService.  By changing the process attribute to .MyBackgroundService, the services now show up.  WHEW!

Comment: Also, you can add `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()` inside your starting code, so you can wait for the debugger to attach. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/DftP5gYcwYI/j_mccTSCHNQJ

Answer (score 0):

### IntelliJ >= 2022

1. In the Android Run/Debug configuration select `Deploy: Default APK` and `Launch: Nothing`.
2. If cannot attach, use the `Attach Debugger to Android Process` button:

[image]